# JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

With this javascript:

```
var title = snap.child("title").val();
var content = snap.child("content").val();
$("#comments").append(" <div class="mdl-card__title">
<h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">"+ title +"</h2>
  </div>
   <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    "+ content +"
    </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
     <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-
      effect">
      Get Started
    </a>
</div>
<div class="mdl-card__menu">
   <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-
   effect">
  <i class="material-icons">share</i>
 </button>
</div>");
 });
```

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes using back slash

Comment: Escape double quotes like `\"` or use single quotes `" '...' " ` between double  quotes

Comment: can you tell me how, i am beginner to web development

Comment: You have it right there in the duplicate - Read it and learn how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape the `double quotes` using `back slash`

```
var title = snap.child("title").val();
var content = snap.child("content").val();
$("#comments").append(" <div class=\"mdl-card__title\">
<h2 class=\"mdl-card__title-text\">"+ title +"</h2>
  </div>
   <div class=\"mdl-card__supporting-text\">
    "+ content +"
    </div>
  <div class=\"mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border\">
     <a class=\"mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-
      effect\">
      Get Started
    </a>
</div>
<div class=\"mdl-card__menu\">
   <button class=\"mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-
   effect\">
  <i class=\"material-icons\">share</i>
 </button>
</div>");
 });
```

Comment: show the same error

Comment: you showed middle of code .show entire code @MuhammadNeamany

Comment: thank you it is worked .... but I have CSS style for this html and I want to make it function, can you tell me how ?

Comment: It's totally new question . you just post another question  after sometimes with clear explanation  . people will help you and i too . if my answer is useful mark it with green ticks it's useful for future user reference @MuhammadNeamany